# HttpClient won't import in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a simple class written in Android Studio:

```
package com.mysite.myapp;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

public class Whatever {
    public void headBangingAgainstTheWallExample () {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

and from this I get the following compile time error:

`Cannot resolve symbol HttpClient`

Isn't `HttpClient` included in the Android Studio SDK? Even if it is not, I added it to my Gradle build like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

With or without the last compile line, the error is the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to use `AndroidHttpClient` if you can. HttpClient stubs are indeed contained inside the android jar, so there should be no need to refer to it explicitly. Note that the android version of httpclient is probably 4.1.1. Trying to use a newer version on top of that is usually asking for trouble (read: doesn't work, because the firmware classloader always wins).

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32157466/1085264

Answer (score 835, accepted):

`HttpClient` is not supported any more in SDK 23. You have to use `URLConnection` or downgrade to SDK 22 (`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`)

If you need SDK 23, add this to your gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary("org.apache.http.legacy")
}
```

You also may try to download and include [`HttpClient` jar](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) directly into your project or use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) instead

Comment: Announcement link: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: It doesn't do anything in my case. How come?

Comment: useLibrary cannot be resolved when I add it. My target is 23, what i'm I missing?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I was the same. See my answer below.

Comment: They use this in license vending code. Have they upgraded this for M also?

Comment: `android {
            useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }`
**[when u add this]**
**[1]** 'org.apache.http' android-studio still have tips:'Cannot resolve symbol' 
**[2]** this make android-studio(with sdk23) can build. though there have tips(Cannot resolve symbol)
**[3]** if u add jar,it no tips,can build,but!!!cannot run,because it has two copy 'org.apache.http'

Comment: @YETI did you remove httpclient import from gradle when you try to use jar?

Comment: @androiddeveloper did you succeed with importing jar?

Comment: @IlyaBlokh No. We will probably use OkHttp or something.

Comment: @llyaBloch  **(1)** User jars **(2)** Use/Unuse [useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'] **(result1)** can build **(result2)** cannot run:[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2]

Comment: useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' works like a dream for me, add, sync gradle and i can use httpclient! thanks man, saved me a lot of time from re-writing the code!

Comment: For anyone out there using the `Volley` library, take note that this gradle line addition should go into the gradle file for the library, and not your app. Works perfectly! Thanks a ton!

Comment: `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` works fine in SDK 30, thanks

Answer (score 165):

HttpClient was deprecated in API Level 22 and removed in API Level 23. You can still use it in API Level 23 and onwards if you must, however it is best to move to supported methods to handle HTTP. So, if you're compiling with 23, add this in your build.gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary("org.apache.http.legacy")
}
```

Comment: `android {
            useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }`
**[when u add this]**
**[1]** 'org.apache.http' android-studio still have tips:'Cannot resolve symbol' 
**[2]** this make android-studio(with sdk23) can build. though there have tips(Cannot resolve symbol)
**[3]** if u add jar,it no tips,can build,but!!!cannot run,because it has two copy 'org.apache.http'

Comment: **[2.1]** So close Android Studio and start it again, don't open the file(s) that make use of the legacy code and the "tips" won't be applied. If you need to open the file then it suggests you own the code, so **[4]** you should stop using HttpClient in code you control.

Comment: Donot know why (build-tool&sdk)23's behavious so freak. Event donot support developer use 'apche http' on one's mind.

Comment: You have to update the android studio to the latest version to avoid this behavior......its fixed in the new version

Comment: What are the "supported methods to handle HTTP"?

Comment: @waldgeist behold the power of search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058727/i-need-an-alternative-option-to-httpclient-in-android-to-send-data-to-php-as-it

Comment: Thanks. I’ve seen this, but these APIs seem to be way more low level than the Apache APIs.

Comment: @waldgeist I don't know what your particular needs are, have a look at Retrofit

Comment: @straya: Thanks, will do!

Answer (score 67):

TejaDroid's answer in below link helped me .  [Can't import org.apache.http.HttpResponse in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340629/cant-import-org-apache-http-httpresponse-in-android-studio)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks this is the only solution that worked with the new eperimental builds as useLibrary is not recognised in it

Comment: This is actually a better answer than the one above! it works with newer versions of the compiler

Answer (score 47):

To use Apache HTTP for SDK Level 23:

**Top level build.gradle - /build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' 
        // Lowest version for useLibrary is 1.3.0
        // Android Studio will notify you about the latest stable version
        // See all versions: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
    }
    ...
}
```

Notification from Android studio about gradle update:

[image: Notification from Android studio about gradle update]

**Module specific build.gradle - /app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    ...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Try this
worked for me
Add this dependency to your build.gradle File

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

Answer (score 16):

1- download Apache jar files (as of this answer) 4.5.zip file from:
https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi?Preferred=http%3A%2F%2Fapache.arvixe.com%2F

2- open the zip copy the jar files into your libs folder. You can find it if you go to the top of your project where it says "Android" you'll find a list when u click it. So,

> Android -> Project -> app -> libs

,Then put jars there.

3- In build.gradle (Module: app) add

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

in

```
 dependency { 
   }
```

4- In the java class add these imports:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
```

Answer (score 15):

HttpClient is not supported any more in sdk 23. Android 6.0 (API Level 23) release removes support for the Apache HTTP client.
You have to use

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    .
    .
    .
```

and also add below code snippet in your dependency :

//http final solution for web-service (including file uploading)

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
 compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

It will also help you while you use Use **MultipartEntity** for **File upload**.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you :)

Comment: I have problems with that...  duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpHeaders.class. Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 10):

If you want import some class like :

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
```

You can add the following line in the build.gradle (Gradle dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'

    .
    .
    .

    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! I had to use the wrapped.org.apache since I needed to update a very old project. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

in API 22 they become deprecated and in API 23 they removed them completely, a simple workaround if you don't need all the fancy stuff from the new additions is to simply use the .jar files from apache that were integrated before API 22, but as separated .jar files:

```
1. http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
2. download httpclient 4.5.1, the zile file
3. unzip all files
4. drag in your project httpclient-4.5.1.jar, httpcore-4.4.3.jar and httpmime-4.5.1.jar
5. project, right click, open module settings, app, dependencies, +, File dependency and add the 3 files
6. now everything should compile properly
```

Answer (score 7):

As of April 2021, you can use the following:

In your app gradle, add the following under 'dependencies { ':

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
```

In your Java activity, add the following import:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
```

You should then be able to add HttpClient to your method(s).

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add this to Gradle dependencies:

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2"
```

Comment: This helps. But still not enough if you want to use other classes like `HttpGet`. For that I used `compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'`

Answer (score 6):

Android 6.0 (API Level 23) release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. Hence you can not use this library directly in API 23. But there is a way to use it. Add useLibrary ‘org.apache.http.legacy’ in your build.gradle file as below-

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

If this does not work you may apply the following hack-

– Copy org.apache.http.legacy.jar which is in /platforms/android-23/optional path of your Android SDK directory to your project’s app/libs folder.

– Now Add compile files(‘libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar’) inside dependencies{} section of build.gradle file.

Comment: The last option you gave does the job well. I appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

ApacheHttp Client is removed in v23 sdk. You can use HttpURLConnection  or third party Http Client like OkHttp.

ref : `https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client`

Comment: Use of `HttpUrlConnection` is actually encouraged in lieu of HttpClient

Answer (score 5):

You have to add just one line

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

into build.gradle(Module: app), for example

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avenues.lib.testotpappnew"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this :-

```
android {
         .
         .
         .
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
         .
         .
         .
          }
```

Answer (score 4):

HttpClient is not supported in sdk 23 and 23+.

If you need to use into sdk 23, add below code to your gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Its working for me. Hope useful for you.

Comment: Worked perfectly with SDK version 24

Answer (score 4):

If you need sdk 23, add this to your gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned before, `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` is not supported any more in:

SDK (API level) #23.

You have to use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.

If you want to make your code (and life) easier when using `HttpURLConnection`, here is a `Wrapper` of this class that will let you do simple operations with `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` using `JSON`, like for example, doing a `HTTP PUT`.

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(API_URL + PATH).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
int httpCode = request.put(new JSONObject().toString());
if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == httpCode) {
    response = request.getJSONObjectResponse();
} else {
  // log error
}
httpRequest.close()
```

Feel free to use it.

```
package com.calculistik.repository;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.
 * <p>
 * Copyright © 2017, Calculistik . All rights reserved.
 * <p>
 * Oracle and Java are registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its
 * affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
 * <p>
 * The contents of this file are subject to the terms of either the GNU
 * General Public License Version 2 only ("GPL") or the Common
 * Development and Distribution License("CDDL") (collectively, the
 * "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the
 * License. You can obtain a copy of the License at
 * https://netbeans.org/cddl-gplv2.html or
 * nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP. See the License for the specific
 * language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 * When distributing the software, include this License Header
 * Notice in each file and include the License file at
 * nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP. Oracle designates this particular file
 * as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided by Oracle in the
 * GPL Version 2 section of the License file that accompanied this code. If
 * applicable, add the following below the License Header, with the fields
 * enclosed by brackets [] replaced by your own identifying information:
 * "Portions Copyrighted [year] [name of copyright owner]"
 * <p>
 * Contributor(s):
 * Created by alejandro tkachuk @aletkachuk
 * www.calculistik.com
 */
public class HttpRequest {

    public static enum Method {
        POST, PUT, DELETE, GET;
    }

    private URL url;
    private HttpURLConnection connection;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HttpRequest(String url) throws IOException {
        this.url = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) this.url.openConnection();
    }

    public int get() throws IOException {
        return this.send();
    }

    public int post(String data) throws IOException {
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(Method.POST.toString());
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        this.sendData(data);
        return this.send();
    }

    public int post() throws IOException {
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(Method.POST.toString());
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        return this.send();
    }

    public int put(String data) throws IOException {
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(Method.PUT.toString());
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        this.sendData(data);
        return this.send();
    }

    public int put() throws IOException {
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(Method.PUT.toString());
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        return this.send();
    }

    public HttpRequest addHeader(String key, String value) {
        connection.setRequestProperty(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public HttpRequest addParameter(String key, String value) {
        this.params.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONObjectResponse() throws JSONException, IOException {
        return new JSONObject(getStringResponse());
    }

    public JSONArray getJSONArrayResponse() throws JSONException, IOException {
        return new JSONArray(getStringResponse());
    }

    public String getStringResponse() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) response.append(line + "\n");
        return response.toString();
    }

    public byte[] getBytesResponse() throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int bytesRead; (bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) >= 0; )
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        return output.toByteArray();
    }

    public void close() {
        if (null != connection)
            connection.disconnect();
    }

    private int send() throws IOException {
        int httpStatusCode = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;

        if (!this.params.isEmpty()) {
            this.sendData();
        }
        httpStatusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        return httpStatusCode;
    }

    private void sendData() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            result.append((result.length() > 0 ? "&" : "") + entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());//appends: key=value (for first param) OR &key=value(second and more)
        }
        sendData(result.toString());
    }

    private HttpRequest sendData(String query) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.close();
        return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Which API target do you have within your project?`AndroidHttpClient`is only for API Level 8 <.
and please have a look on [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/dependency-info.html)

enjoy your code:)

Answer (score 2):

> Another way is if you have **httpclient.jar** file then you can do
>   this :

Paste your .jar file in "libs folder" in your project. Then in gradle add this line in your build.gradle(Module:app)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these two lines under dependencies

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

then

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

under the android

Answer (score 0):

Error:(30, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:

The project 'cid' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project

The project 'cid' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Answer (score 0):

For android API 28 and higher
in Manifest.xml inside application tag

```
    <application
    .
    .
    .

    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i removed httpcclient libraries and added the line mentioned below then it started working. This library seem to have httpclient classes wrapper inside it.

```
implementation("net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-android:2.63.0")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think depending on which Android Studio version you have, it's important you update your android studio as well, i was becoming frustrated too following everyone's advice but no luck, until i had to upgrade my android version from 1.3 to 1.5, the errors disappeared like magic.