# Using Apache HttpClient with Android SDK 23. NoSuchMethod

Tags: android, apache, sdk, apache-httpclient-4.x

Already created a [bugticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184323&thanks=184323&ts=1441026837) at Google for this.
Possibly anyone has any ideas?

I wanted to use a normal `HTTPClient` (CloseableHttpClient) within Apache Library,

```
mCloseableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
                .setUserAgent(userAgent)
                .build();
```

and the Application always directly crashes with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:912)
```

**starting** at **API Level 22** (**same** for API Level **23**).

The problem is: The class within the Android SDK **doesn't have** **INSTANCE** field declared.

Comment: Post your gradle.app where you put the comile

Comment: it is starting to duplicate, please kindly search android M httpclient legacy

Comment: @ Revanth Rev and cV2, please check the following link where the solution of your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340629/cant-import-org-apache-http-httpresponse-in-android-studio/32649055#32649055

Answer (score 4):

The following class has been removed as of API level 22

```
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier
```

You can see the removed classes in the official [api changes](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/22/changes.html)

You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) class instead.

According to [official guide](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

> This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption

** **EDIT** **

According to CommonsWare's comment below, there are also other 3rd party options including [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Apache's separate HttpClient library for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)

Comment: "You have to use HttpURLConnection class instead" -- no. While HttpClient itself is removed, and `HttpURLConnection` is an option, there are other options, such as [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Apache's separate HttpClient library for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry English is not my native language, I edited my statement. Thank you.

Comment: this problem is not related, as i described… the google bug report was rated as "medium && defect…" so … there's an issue as described…

Comment: You can also add
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

see this post --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio

Comment: Another powerful library is [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), which is in many cases an easier and faster library to use. And it does support HTTPS (SSL)

Answer (score -1):

Is a problem of a library version try with this versions

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
    api 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
    api 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
```