# Can't import org.apache.http.HttpResponse in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I want to use these libraries in Android Studio:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

I am following a video tutorial in which the tutor is using Eclipse so I know it works.

But what additional things/libraries do I have to add to Android Studio in order to use them?

Comment: Do you have the dependencies in your gradle file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

HttpClient was deprecated in Android 5.1 and is removed from the Android SDK in Android 6.0. While there is [a workaround to continue using HttpClient in Android 6.0 with Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client), you really need to move to something else. That "something else" could be:

- the built-in classic Java `HttpUrlConnection`
- Apache's independent packaging of [HttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)
- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) (my recommendation)
- [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)

Or, depending upon the nature of your HTTP work, you might choose a library that supports higher-order operations (e.g., Retrofit for Web service APIs).

In a pinch, you could enable the legacy APIs, by having `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your `android` closure in your module's `build.gradle` file. However, Google has been advising people for years to stop using Android's built-in HttpClient, and so at most, this should be a stop-gap move, while you work on a more permanent shift to another API.

Answer (score 66):

**HttpClient is deprecated in sdk 23**.

You have to move on URLConnection or down sdk to 22

> Still you need HttpClient with update gradle sdk 23

You have to add the dependencies of HttpClient in app/gradle as

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Whoever using An Asynchronous HTTP Library and SDK 23, 
You will need to follow @TejaDroid 's answer.

Comment: Add it to the app/gradle

Comment: But was getting error in     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

Comment: @garima, I think there need to be same of `buildToolsVersion` and compile lib version. means if you have `buildToolsVersion` = `23.0.2` then use `appcompat` version `23.0.2`.

Answer (score 24):

Main build.gradle - /build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1' 
        // Versions: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
    }
    ...
}
```

Module specific build.gradle - /app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    ...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

Comment: We shouldn't modify the "Main build gradle". right??

Anyway, I inserted the line: useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' in the app/build/gradle and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Apache site this is the Gradle dependency you need to include, if you use Android API 23 or newer:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}
```

Source: 
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html

Answer (score 0):

in case you are going to start development, go fot OkHttp from square, otherwise if you need to keep your previous code running, then add legacy library to your project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use This:-

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

Comment: The other answer already included this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32649055/2308683