# HtmlUnit Android: NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier

Tags: android, kotlin, htmlunit

I'm trying to run HtmlUnit on Android. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366430/getting-nosuchfielderror-instance-org-apache-http-message-basicheadervalueparser/27398616) used to work with the older libs, but not anymore. The other threads related to this question are not about Kotlin on Android or are outdated.

Consider below code:

https://github.com/JimClermonts/HtmlUnit-for-Android

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    doAsync {
        val webClient = WebClient()
        var page: HtmlPage = webClient.getPage<HtmlPage>("http://www.google.com")
        val searchBox = page.getElementByName<HtmlInput>("q")
        searchBox.valueAttribute = "htmlunit"

        val googleSearchSubmitButton: HtmlSubmitInput = page.getElementByName("btnG") // sometimes it's "btnK"
        page = googleSearchSubmitButton.click()

        val resultStatsDiv: HtmlDivision = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='resultStats']")

        System.out.println(resultStatsDiv.asText()) // About 309,000 results

        webClient.close()
    }
}
```

Here are my project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
//    implementation group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    implementation group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.6'
    implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit-core-js', version: '2.34.0'
    implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit-cssparser', version: '1.3.0'
    implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'neko-htmlunit', version: '2.34.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.6'
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'websocket-client', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
    implementation group: 'xalan', name: 'xalan', version: '2.7.2'

    //Project Transitive Dependencies
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.7') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
//    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.11'
//    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.7') {
//        exclude module: 'httpclient'
//    }
//    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
////    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.11'
//    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-client', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
//    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-http', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
//    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-io', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
//    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-util', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
//    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-xml', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
//    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'websocket-api', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
//    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'websocket-common', version: '9.4.15.v20190215'
//    implementation group: 'xalan', name: 'serializer', version: '2.7.2'
//    implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.12.0'
//    implementation group: 'xml-apis', name: 'xml-apis', version: '1.4.01'


    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:0.10.1"
}
```

Androidmanifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The error message:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes3.dex)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:149)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.buildSSLSocketFactory(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:89)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.configureHttpsScheme(HttpWebConnection.java:626)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:558)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClientBuilder(HttpWebConnection.java:519)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:171)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1402)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.712 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1321)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:315)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:466)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:448)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at eu.theappfactory.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:20)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at eu.theappfactory.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:12)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$doAsync$1.invoke(Async.kt:140)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$doAsync$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$sam$Callable$761a5578.call(Unknown Source:2)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-04-12 09:17:06.713 5110-5140/eu.theappfactory.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Is your code proguarded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Using Apache HttpClient with Android SDK 23. NoSuchMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312932/using-apache-httpclient-with-android-sdk-23-nosuchmethod).

Answer (score 0):

There is android modified or better say just android working version on github called 'htmlunit android'.
The problem you are facing is due http client, which is allready part of an android framework, but google midified.
For ssl operations htmlunit library need complete apache http library.
There is the message from.
After day of debugging i found that there is some missing classes that htmlunit webrequest need to have to complete calls.
use this library:
https://github.com/null-dev/HtmlUnit-Android

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 2.52.0 the number of classes depending on java.awt is much lower now. If you like a solution for the rest please open an issue on github and i will try to find a way for the remaining dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There reason for this error is a class version clash between HtmlUnit (using HttpClient) and and the version of the HttpClient partly integrated inside the android jdk.

There is now a special distribution of HtmlUnit available at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android that solves this problem.

Please try and report any problems.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you specify the transitive dependencies, you don't need to unless you want to configure it in someway.

I commented them out, and the app compiled and deployed to a device.

Comment: sure the project compiles and deploys but then crashes.