# Not able to send additional parameters with image using HttpURLConnection in android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, image-upload

```
public class UploadProfilePicActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView imageView;
Button btnUploadPic;
Button btnskipUploadPic;
Button btnSaveNContinue;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
String imagepath = null;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String url_profilePic;
private int serverResponseCode;
String api = "http://192.168.2.17:8000/api/v1/";
String format = "/?format=json";
AlmabayDatabase almabayDatabase;
String encodedString;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploadprofilepic);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btnUploadPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadPic);
    btnskipUploadPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkipUploadPic);
    btnSaveNContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveNContinue);
    btnUploadPic.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSaveNContinue.setOnClickListener(this);
    url_profilePic = api + "user-media" + format;
    almabayDatabase = new AlmabayDatabase(this);

      }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnUploadPic) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    } else if (v == btnSaveNContinue) {

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadProfilePicActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
        //  messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.e("ImagePathTest", imagepath);

                uploadFile(imagepath);

            }
        }).start();
    }
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Log.e("Uploading", "Uploading File :" + imagepath);
                }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}


    public int uploadFile(String imagepath) {

    String fileName = imagepath;
    Log.e("File Name", fileName);

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName);
    int pk = almabayDatabase.getUserID();

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                                   Log.e("Sourcefile", "File doesn't exist");
            }
        });
        return 0;
    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(url_profilePic);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("name", fileName);
          //  conn.setRequestProperty("timeline_id", String.valueOf(pk));

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            //Send Image
            Log.e("Sending","Sending Image");
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // add parameter timeline_id
            String timeline_id = String.valueOf(pk);
            Log.e("Sending","Sending PK");
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"timeline_id\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dos.writeBytes(timeline_id);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("ResponseCode", String.valueOf(serverResponseCode));
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file failed", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

}

In this code ,I am trying to send image to server alongwith timeline_id .timeline_id contains the value pk that is the primary key of the user stored in the database.I am not able to send image with timeline_id.I don't know where the actual problem is.Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: You can use below method to send the JSON with multiple images'

Answer (score 5):

You can simple put the file part along with the text part using the class below.

```
 String charset = "UTF-8";
 String requestURL = BASE_URL + "userregistration";

      MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(requestURL, charset);
      multipart.addFormField("username", userJid);
      multipart.addFilePart("image", imageBitmap);//ima
      String response = multipart.finish();
      Log.d("SERVER REPLIED", response);
```

You can create an MultipartUtility class as follow-

```
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     *
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("api_key", "a05f9ece-cd34-11e4-afdc-1681e6b88ec1");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     *
     * @param name  field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--").
                append(boundary).
                append(LINE_FEED).
                append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").
                append(name).append("\"").
                append(LINE_FEED).
                append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=").
                append(charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     *
     * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param fileBytes a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, byte[] fileBytes)
            throws IOException {
//        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--")
                .append(boundary)
                .append(LINE_FEED)
                .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"")
                .append(fieldName)
                .append("\"; filename=\"")
                .append("user.jpeg")
                .append("\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED)
                .append("Content-Type: image/jpeg")
                .append(LINE_FEED)
                .append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary")
                .append(LINE_FEED)
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     *
     * @param name  - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name).append(": ").append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     *
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public String finish() throws IOException {
        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--")
                .append(boundary)
                .append("--")
                .append(LINE_FEED)
                .close();
        String data = "";
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                data = data + line;
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }
        return data.isEmpty() ? null : data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great work. Do you know how I would modify this solution if I want to replace a possible file on the server that happens to have the same name?

Comment: Your approach is very easy and I tried it .But when I execute it , the server does not gets the image .Could you please help?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue.Just need to do the following changes in the uploadFile() method.Everything is working file now.

```
public int uploadFile(String imagepath) {

    String fileName = imagepath;
    Log.e("File Name", fileName);

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName);
    int pk = almabayDatabase.getUserID();

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                Log.e("Sourcefile", "File doesn't exist");
            }
        });
        return 0;
    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(url_profilePic);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("url", fileName);
           // conn.setRequestProperty("timeline_id", String.valueOf(pk));

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            // add parameter timeline_id
            String timeline_id = String.valueOf(pk);
            Log.e("Sending", "Sending PK");
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"timeline_id\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // assign value
            dos.writeBytes(timeline_id);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            //Send Image
            Log.e("Sending", "Sending Image");
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"url\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("ResponseCode", String.valueOf(serverResponseCode));
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file failed", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

Comment: I used your code for uploading image.When I execute it ,it gives server response as OK but when I check my server to see if image is uploaded or not ,the image isn't there on the server.Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the below method to send multiple files with json request...

mImagePath is the arraylist of image paths

```
// Method for sending files using multiparting......
public static String sendJsonWithFile(Activity mActivity, ArrayList<String> mImagePaths, String jsonString, String URL)
{
    Log.e("json", jsonString);
    String res = "";
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        boundary = "--" + boundary;
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    StringBody stringBody = new StringBody(jsonString);

    reqEntity.addPart("formstring", stringBody);

    for (int i = 0; i < mImagePaths.size(); i++)
    {
        String imagePath = mImagePaths.get(i);
        if (mImagePaths != null && mImagePaths.size() > 0)
        {

            byte[] filebytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imagePath));

            ByteArrayBody filebodyImage = new ByteArrayBody(filebytes, "image");
            Log.e("file path=", filebodyImage.toString());

            reqEntity.addPart("image", filebodyImage);

        }

    }

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        res = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    res = "UnsupportedEncodingException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e)
{
    res = "ClientProtocolException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    res = "FileNotFoundException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    res = "IOException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    res = "Exception";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return res;
}
```

Comment: ,I can not use HttpClient as i am working on API 23.It is of no use now.I have to use HttpURLConnection and i have only one image which have to be sent to server along with timeline_id here .

Comment: I tested HttpClient on API 23 and it is working for me. And "mImagePath" is the array of image paths if you have one image then you can add only one  path and the method will work

Comment: Sir, there is no class like HttpClient in API 23 now.I am forced to use HttpURLConnection.I am using android studio 1.3.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153434/4360419 , Use this...!
And I will also update the answer for HttpURLConnection

Comment: Arsal Imam,Have you find the solution using HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Question is using URLConnection not Http Client.