# Android - Using multipart/form-data for additional information with file to be uploaded by PHP

Tags: php, android, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file (which i am currently successful at)

I need to add additional information on the same request on which i am uploading file (which i am unsuccessful at)

Current **Working** code in AsyncTask is as follows

```
if (selectedFilePath == null)
            return 0;
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                String SERVER_URL = "http://isirs.org/intellischools_teachers_app/teachers_script/upload_api.php";
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);



                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "", line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
                reader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                Log.e("reply_upload",response);

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    SendMessageActivity.this,
                                    "File Upload completed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(SendMessageActivity.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(SendMessageActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(SendMessageActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }

}
```

and My php code which accepts the file(**working**) is as follows

```
?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

**Now I need to add additional information so that i can get it using $_POST['details'] method**

**OR**

**Any other solution you have**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32585844/6517251) on a different post on StackOverFlow

Use this whoever is in need

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I have found to do this using a `HttpUrlConnection` is via putting the additional info directly onto the URL. ex:

```
String SERVER_URL = "http://isirs.org/intellischools_teachers_app/teachers_script/upload_api.php?name1=value1&name2=value2";
```

Once you append these arguments onto your URL, you can access them via `$_GET['name1']` and `$_GET['name2']` etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can never use a GET method since it has sensitive information. I have found an alternate [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32585844/6517251). Thanks for your help anyways @LoganRodie