# org.apache.http jar class not found in android studio projects

Tags: android, jar, build, android-gradle-plugin, executable-jar

i  include following jars see below image. 
[image]

I want to integrate json web service so i import below jars

```
apache-mim44j-0.-6.jar
gson-2.1.jar
httpmime-4.0.1.jar
json_simple-1.1.jar
```

**build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'


 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pkg.android.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }


  }


   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  }
```

when i set above structure my jar file is not getting in my class file any idea how can i solve this problem?your all suggestions are appreciable.

**EDIT**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'


 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pkg.android.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }


  }

 android {
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
 }
   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  }
```

Comment: you try like this go module setting of the application select the dependencies and press add button 3 option come select file dependencies add the jar file

Comment: Nithinlal : can you expalin in more detail i m not getting

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpClient won't import in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio)

Comment: compile files('libs/apache-mim44j-0.-6.jar') add this to build. gradle and try

Comment: Right click on your project and select the  module setting -> select the tab dependencies -> you can see a plus button on the right side -> while press this button you got 3 option -> select the file  dependencies -> while doing this a window will option select your jar which needed to add

Comment: Nithinlal : i try same thing but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Apache HTTP Client was removed since API level 23:

> This preview removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app
>   is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher,
>   use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient
>   because it reduces network use through transparent compression and
>   response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using
>   the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following
>   compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
>     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
> }
> ```
>
> Android is moving away from OpenSSL to the BoringSSL library. If
>   you’re using the Android NDK in your app, don't link against
>   cryptographic libraries that are not a part of the NDK API, such as
>   libcrypto.so and libssl.so. These libraries are not public APIs, and
>   may change or break without notice across releases and devices. In
>   addition, you may expose yourself to security vulnerabilities.
>   Instead, modify your native code to call the Java cryptography APIs
>   via JNI or to statically link against a cryptography library of your
>   choice.
>
> Reference:
>   https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: Mattia : see my edit portion i make change as per your answer but still class not found

Comment: You already have an element `android`. Don't create another one, just add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in the existing element.

Comment: Mattia: [http://pastie.org/10435380](http://pastie.org/10435380) see this link any modification needed because still not getting sucess

Comment: What is the version of Gradle tools you use? You need the version 1.3.0, check your  project-level build.gradle.

Comment: i have com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'  gradle level

Comment: It's a known bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181474. Android Studio can't find the classes and gives errors, but the project builds correctly. The bug is marked as FutureRelease, so we need to wait a new release of Android Studio that fix the issue. In the meantime you can still use Apache HTTP Client ignoring the class not found error

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
[link](http://www.us.apache.org/dist//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.5.1-bin.zip) to download all libs. and then include

httpclient-4.5.1.jar
httpcore-4.4.3.jar

and if get confilcts use these lines in buil.gradel

```
android {
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

if get any more, click on highlited import and Alt+Enter.
got solved by this