# The system cannot find the file(httpclient-4.0.1.jar) specified in android studio?

Tags: android

The system cannot find the file (httpclient-4.0.1.jar) specified in android studio ?

I am trying to create a new app in Android Studio, When I try to Run or debug it shows a compile time error like :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':SampleApp:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\VM\Desktop\SampleApp\libs\httpclient-4.0.1.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

build.gradle(Module:SampleApp) file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.SampleApp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
      manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId : "${applicationId}",
           onesignal_app_id  : " ",
           onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    } } dependencies {
    compile project(':library_pull_to_refresh')
    compile project(':view_pager_indicator')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.6.jar')
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7+' }
```

Even after that I can't find any solution.

Please any one guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.http jar class not found in android studio projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690497/org-apache-http-jar-class-not-found-in-android-studio-projects)

Answer (score 1):

Apache HTTP Client was removed since API level 23:

> This preview removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app
>   is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher,
>   use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient
>   because it reduces network use through transparent compression and
>   response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using
>   the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following
>   compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
>     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
> }
> ```
>
> Android is moving away from OpenSSL to the BoringSSL library. If
>   you’re using the Android NDK in your app, don't link against
>   cryptographic libraries that are not a part of the NDK API, such as
>   libcrypto.so and libssl.so. These libraries are not public APIs, and
>   may change or break without notice across releases and devices. In
>   addition, you may expose yourself to security vulnerabilities.
>   Instead, modify your native code to call the Java cryptography APIs
>   via JNI or to statically link against a cryptography library of your
>   choice.
>
> Reference:
>   https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HttpClient for http request and response you can use HTTP Library by adding this line in your app gradle instead of adding jar file :-

```
 android
{
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From where you downloaded your .jar file? I just downloaded it from "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1" right now and it works.
Upd.: also you can try to add "compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.0.1'" instead "compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')"