# Apache http client error with json version provided by android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to parse json from url, Apache http client removed from Android API level 23. If I use `httpclient.jar` files in android studio, it shows error like:

> "Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it
>   may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android."

```
dependencies{

    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.5.1.jar')
}
```

How to resolve this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you including json? Json comes with Android.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the above two statements from your `build.gradle` and add the following dependency

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Comment: Can you post you build.gradle file?

Comment: i posted my gradle file as answer

Comment: Change `targetSdkVersion` to 23 and everything will be good to go. Apache API were removed in Android API 23. They were depricated in Android API 22. That is why the warning.

Comment: Did that remove the warning?

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to use apache client in sdk23. doDo you try to useadd this code in gradle.

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

see [HttpClient won't import in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

this is my gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies{

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:engine.io-client:0.6.0'
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1'
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.5.1.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
```

}