# Getting Can't find common super class of [com/loopj/android/http/MySSLSocketFactory] after enabling Pro-guard

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, proguard

After enabling pro-guard, I was receiving around 1000 warnings. So after adding rules and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255810/4977669) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686136/4977669) answers on Stackoverflow, I am now receiving 1 warning and 1 error.

This is what i am getting now.

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of
>   [com/loopj/android/http/MySSLSocketFactory] (with 1 known super
>   classes) and [java/security/KeyStore] (with 2 known super classes)
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/loopj/android/http/MySSLSocketFactory]
> >     (with 1 known super classes) and [java/security/KeyStore] (with 2
> >     known super classes)

proguard-rules.pro

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''


#---------------TEST

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**

-keep class com.conviva.**
-dontwarn com.conviva.**

-keep class com.loopj.android.http.**
-keep class org.apache.http.**
-keep class rx.internal.util.**
-keep class com.algolia.search.**

-dontwarn com.loopj.android.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn rx.internal.util.**
-dontwarn com.algolia.search.**

-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient

-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient

-keep class com.loopj.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.loopj.android.** { *; }


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}


#---------------TEST






-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

#---------------Begin: proguard configuration for support library  ----------
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version. We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.example.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

**gradle**

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}
```

**EDIT**

This is how i am enabling pro-guard in `app` `build.gralde` file, I am using `'proguard-android-optimize.txt`

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

add this:

```
-keep class cz.msebera.android.httpclient.** { *; }
-dontwarn cz.msebera.android.httpclient.**
```

**Update:**
try this:

```
-keep class com.loopj.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.loopj.android.** { *; }
-keep class cz.msebera.android.** { *; }
-keep interface cz.msebera.android.** { *; }
-dontwarn cz.msebera.android.**
-dontwarn com.loopj.android.**
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Its still giving me the same error messages

Comment: It is still there, If i remove this `('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),`  and use normal `('proguard-android.txt'),` It does not display any error message, but also it stops working and does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using any third party library like retrofit or okHttp for network calls. In such cases, e.g. retrofit has removed the support "org.apache.http package". Try this...

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest
-dontwarn retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest
-dontwarn retrofit.client.ApacheClient$TypedOutputEntity
```

You can refer here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1019

Comment: Yes there are third party libraries that are using retrofit library in my app

Comment: Minification would fail because retrofit v1 depends on removed "org.apache.http" package. You can try adding following lines to your proguard rules. (see updated answer..)