# How to solve this imports in Android studio

Tags: url, https

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

How to solve this, help me out I'm new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the libraries to the gradle file.

Look for this line:

```
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

and add this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4' 
}
```

Comment: I'm new I dnt knw how to do this

Comment: I jxt want to make a connection Imdoing json parsing , jxt this Http thing is remaining

Comment: Can you show me your imports in that Java file? Did you write that code or is it copy-paste?

Comment: import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

Comment: and yes I following a tutorial , I was doing the samebut in end I got these , import error I dnt knw why

Comment: Open your gradle file (there are two) and look for this:

Comment: compile { ... } add this inside 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4'

Comment: You can see an example here: https://github.com/juleswhite/mobilecloud-15/blob/master/assignments/assignment2/build.gradle

Comment: import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

Comment: Add this: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0-alpha4'

Comment: hmm, try this: compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

Comment: if that does not work then you can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Please explain your question... If you want to fetch from http, below code will help you. you may need to add some libraries too.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
Httppost httppost = new HttpPost("www.example.com");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
entity = response.getEntity(); 
InputStream is = entity.getContent(); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
  sb.append(line + "\n"); 
} 
is.close(); 
String result = sb.toString(); 
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
```

continue your code after this...

Comment: I was following a tutorial , [link](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/) see this I did the same but , I'm getting import errore