# package org.apache.http.util does not exist

Tags: android-studio

I am trying on my own to implement a useful trip planner application using android studio with the help of goolge and some open sources

I have android application with no gradle.build. when it try to run it i get the error.

```
 Error:(20, 28) java: package org.apache.http.util does not exist
```

Here is the part of the code that has the error.

How to solve the error ?

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    public static String queryUrl(String url) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        Log.i(TAG, "Url:" + url + "");
        Log.i(TAG, "Status:[" + response.getStatusLine().toString() + "]");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }

        instream.close();

        String result = total.toString();
        return result;
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "There was a protocol based error", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "There was some error", e);
    }

    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See following answer, [HttpClient won't import in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio)

I don't know how your module's build.gradle looks like, but I assume you are including apache libraries some wrong way.

Also, I would not reccomend using apache HTTP libraries in new android applications. Have look at [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) or [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley)

I would post this in comments, but I don't have enough reputation yet.